# Finding source voltage, v1, and I1 in a circuit with a current source

Tags: parallel, current-source, series

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8BWB6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Can anyone tell me why this circuit would be considered parallel instead of series?

Comment: Can you tell us what the goal of this circuit is, or what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: This is just a simple circuit.  My objective is to find the voltage across the source, the voltage across the resistor and the current going across the resistor.  This is a sample problem from the book and I haven't been able to get a good explanation of why this is considered parallel instead of series.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for are known as thevenin and norton equivalent circuits.  The Norton has a current source with a parallel resistor and the thevenin has a voltage source with a series resistance.  Your drawing only shows one aspect of the translation.[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment.. We aren't going to cover thevenin and norton until next chapter.  Maybe after I cover that, the reasoning behind it being parallel will make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can call it either. Vs is in parallel with R1 or Vs is in series with R1.

Because there are only two components in the circuit I don't see any other way of drawing it and that, I suspect means it has to be both.

Answer (score 0):

- Ohms law: V = IR
- I = .01 A
- R = 20000 Ω
- V = (0.01 * 20000) = 200 V

And I agree with andy on the parallel series thing.